# Java - Convert a String of letters to an int of corresponding ascii?

Tags: java, ascii

I want to convert a String, lets say `"abc"`, to an int with the corresponding ascii: in this example, `979899`.

I've run into two problems:

1) what I wrote only works for characters whose ascii is two characters long and

2) since these numbers get very big, I can't use longs and I'm having trouble utilizing BigIntegers.

This is what I have so far:

```
BigInteger mInt = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);
for (int i = 0; i<mString.length(); i++) {
        mInt = mInt.add(BigInteger.valueOf(
                (long)(mString.charAt(i)*Math.pow(100,(mString.length()-1-i)))));
}
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Comment: Don't cast to long again. Did you try removing long cast?

Comment: The parameter of valueOf() is long, so I have to.

Comment: Instead of valueOf(), just use Constructor, new BigInteger(String.valueOf(yourCode));http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with doing all the concatenation first with a `StringBuilder` and then creating a `BigInteger` out of the result? This seems to be much simpler than what you're currently doing.

```
String str = "abc";  // or anything else

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray())
    sb.append((int)c);

BigInteger mInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
System.out.println(mInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to play the number game. (pow 100 etc). just get the number string, and pass to constructor.

```
final String s = "abc";
        String v = "";
        final char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            v += String.valueOf((int) chars[i]);
        }
//v = "979899" now
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(v); //BigInteger
        BigDecimal bigDec = new BigDecimal(v); // or BigDecimal
```

Comment: Assuming the string `s` is going to be long, it would probably be better to use a `StringBuilder` performance-wise. Repetitive string concatenations can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

To handle n-digit numbers, you will have to multiply by a different power of ten each time. You could do this with a loop:

```
BigInteger appendDigits(BigInteger total, int n) {
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 10)
        total = total.multiply(10);

    return total.plus(new BigInteger(n));
}
```

However, this problem really seems to be about manipulating strings. What I would probably do is simply accumulate the digits int a string, and create a BI from the String at the end:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : mString.getBytes())
    result.append(String.valueOf(c));
return new BigInteger(result.toString());
```