# Convert character to ASCII numeric value in java

Tags: java, string, ascii

I have `String name = "admin";`
then I do `String charValue = name.substring(0,1); //charValue="a"`

I want to convert the `charValue` to its ASCII value (97), how can I do this in java?

Comment: JW will `String char` ever compile. May be you want to rename the variable to `String ch`

Comment: ASCII? Are you sure that's what you want? Java uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set (just like JavaScript, .NET, VBA, VB4/5/6, NCHAR, NVARCHAR, NTFS, Windows API, …). The answers fall into several categories: answering about ASCII explicitly, answering about UTF-16 and answering about ASCII via several shortcutted leaps from UTF-16 (and also some are just plain wrong).

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Very simple. Just cast your `char` as an `int`.

```
char character = 'a';    
int ascii = (int) character;
```

In your case, you need to get the specific Character from the String first and then cast it.

```
char character = name.charAt(0); // This gives the character 'a'
int ascii = (int) character; // ascii is now 97.
```

Though cast is not required explicitly, but its improves readability.

```
int ascii = character; // Even this will do the trick.
```

Comment: @VKSingla - Agreed its not required, but it improves readability and will help the OP in understanding.

Comment: Why create another char variable? Even if you want the cast why not to do this that way? `int ascii = (int)name.charAt(0);`

Comment: @R.J - ok I hadn't thought about it

Comment: ASCII characters have 7-bit codes from 0 to 127. So no need to use int. byte can perfectly store any code.

Comment: I was looking to convert the int to char, the cast hint helped me to do it the other way around from the answer.

Comment: You say "Very simple. Just cast your char as an int." I do not think it's so simple. Strings in Java use UTF-16 encoding. UTF-16 encoding uses 2 bytes to represent characters. If the `name` variable contains the character `Â` at the `0th` position, I doubt you will get an integer ASCII value when you can it to `int`. It will return `194`. ASCII goes up to `127`. Therefore, to be correct, I would state that you'll get UTF-16 decimal value of the character this way. And ASCII is a subset of UTF-16.

Answer (score 55):

just a different approach

```
    String s = "admin";
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

`bytes[0]` will represent ascii of a.. and thus the other characters in the whole array.

Answer (score 23):

Instead of this:

```
String char = name.substring(0,1); //char="a"
```

You should use the `charAt()` method.

```
char c = name.charAt(0); // c='a'
int ascii = (int)c;
```

Comment: Just to remember that "char" is a reserved word in Java.

Answer (score 17):

The several answers that purport to show how to do this are all wrong because Java characters are not ASCII characters. Java uses a multibyte encoding of Unicode characters. The Unicode character set is a super set of ASCII. So there can be characters in a Java string that do not belong to ASCII. Such characters do not have an ASCII numeric value, so asking how to get the ASCII numeric value of a Java character is unanswerable.

But *why* do you want to do this anyway? What are you going to do with the value?

If you want the numeric value so you can convert the Java String to an ASCII string, the *real* question is "how do I encode a Java String as ASCII". For that, use the object [`StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#US_ASCII).

Comment: Perfect answer. Type casting is just a short-cut that's not accurate. Glad your answer came at start so people don't misunderstand concept.

Comment: The reason I have need to know the ASCII string is because I've got Unicode data coming into a backend process that needs to place pure ASCII somewhere else, and I need to when I'm getting non-Unicode.  Usually when users are copy pasting from MS Word (e.g. curved double and single quotes, long dashes, etc.).
To mention StandardCharsets.US_ASCII is the correct thing to do, but that doesn't tell the original questioner how to use it.

Comment: public static String displayAsciiCode(String s, boolean useStandard) {
         String r = "";
         byte[] ascii = null;
         if (useStandard) {
          ascii = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); 
          for (int i=0; i<ascii.length; i++) {
           byte b= ascii[i];
           r = r + " " + s.charAt(i) + "=" + (int)b;
          }
         } else {
          ascii = s.getBytes();
      for (int i=0; i<ascii.length; i++) {
       byte b= ascii[i];
       r = r + " " + Character.toString ((char) ascii[i]) + "=" + (int)b;
      } 
     }
     return r;
 }

Comment: Call the above with:
    String string = "This “is” strange";
    System.out.println("strings=" + string);
    System.out.println(displayAsciiCode(string, true));
    System.out.println(displayAsciiCode(string, false));

The result is:
    strings=This “is” strange
    T=84 h=104 i=105 s=115  =32 “=63 i=105 s=115 ”=63  =32 s=115 t=116 r=114 a=97 n=110 g=103 e=101
    T=84 h=104 i=105 s=115  =32 ￢=-30 ﾀ=-128 ﾜ=-100 i=105 s=115 ￢=-30 ﾀ=-128 ﾝ=-99  =32 s=115 t=116 r=114 a=97 n=110 g=103 e=101

Answer (score 13):

If you wanted to convert the entire string into concatenated ASCII values then you can use this -

```
    String str = "abc";  // or anything else

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
    sb.append((int)c);

    BigInteger mInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
    System.out.println(mInt);
```

wherein you will get 979899 as output.

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405855/java-convert-a-string-of-letters-to-an-int-of-corresponding-ascii).

I just copied it here so that it would be convenient for others.

Answer (score 7):

Convert the char to int.

```
    String name = "admin";
    int ascii = name.toCharArray()[0];
```

Also :

```
int ascii = name.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just cast the char to an int.

```
char character = 'a';
int number = (int) character;
```

The value of `number` will be 97.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has already been answered in several forms but here is my bit of code with a look to go through all the characters.

Here is the code, started with the class

```
public class CheckChValue {  // Class name
public static void main(String[] args) { // class main

    String name = "admin"; // String to check it's value
    int nameLenght = name.length(); // length of the string used for the loop

    for(int i = 0; i < nameLenght ; i++){   // while counting characters if less than the length add one        
        char character = name.charAt(i); // start on the first character
        int ascii = (int) character; //convert the first character
        System.out.println(character+" = "+ ascii); // print the character and it's value in ascii
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Java uses Unicode for `string` and `char`. A textual unit in Unicode is a grapheme, which is a base codepoint followed by zero or more combining codepoints. A codepoint, in Java, is encoded in UTF-16, which could require one or two 16-bit code units (`char`) for a codepoint. To iterate codepoints, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527891/2226988). Code should already be ready for the up-and-coming U+1F91E HAND WITH INDEX AND MIDDLE FINGERS CROSSED codepoint, for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Ascii {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String a=args[0];
        char [] z=a.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<z.length;i++){ 
            System.out.println((int)z[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, get the character you want, and convert it to int.

```
String name = "admin";
int ascii = name.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way for this is:

```
    int character = 'a';
```

If you print "character", you get 97.

Answer (score 2):

using Java 9 => String.chars()

```
String input = "stackoverflow";
System.out.println(input.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

output - [115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]

Answer (score 2):

One line solution without using extra int variable:

```
String name = "admin";
System.out.println((int)name.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "abc";  // or anything else

// Stores strings of integer representations in sequence
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray())
    sb.append((int)c);

 // store ascii integer string array in large integer
BigInteger mInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
System.out.println(mInt);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = "admin";
char[] ch = name.toString().toCharArray(); //it will read and store each character of String and store into char[].

for(int i=0; i<ch.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(ch[i]+
                       "-->"+
                       (int)ch[i]); //this will print both character and its value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Raedwald pointed out, Java's Unicode doesn't cater to all the characters to get ASCII value. The correct way **(Java 1.7+)** is as follows :

```
byte[] asciiBytes = "MyAscii".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
String asciiString = new String(asciiBytes);
//asciiString = Arrays.toString(asciiBytes)
```

Comment: `new String(byte[])` uses yet another character encoding—the so-called system default, which varies across time, machines and users; almost never useful. What you call `asciiString` is still UTF-16 because that's all Java has.

Comment: @TomBlodget, I agree. But I think OP wanted to know how to get the ASCIIrepresentation of a given character. This is just an encoding as java can't do raw ASCII

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Stream API for 1 character or a String starting in Java 1.8:

```
public class ASCIIConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "adskjfhqewrilfgherqifvehwqfjklsdbnf";
        text.chars()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this we could straight away use String classe's

```
    input.codePointAt(index);
```

I would like to give one more suggestion as to get whole of string converted to corresponding ascii codes, using java 8
for example, "abcde" to "979899100101".

```
    String input = "abcde";
    System.out.println(
            input.codePoints()
                    .mapToObj((t) -> "" + t)
                    .collect(joining()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ASCII´s number with this code.

```
String name = "admin";
char a1 = a.charAt(0);
int a2 = a1;
System.out.println("The number is : "+a2); // the value is 97
```

If I am wrong, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing, but best and easy solution would be to use charAt and to access the indexes we should create an integer array of [128] size.

```
String name = "admin"; 
int ascii = name.charAt(0); 
int[] letters = new int[128]; //this will allocate space with 128byte size.
letters[ascii]++; //increments the value of 97 to 1;
System.out.println("Output:" + ascii); //Outputs 97
System.out.println("Output:" +  letters[ascii]); //Outputs 1 if you debug you'll see 97th index value will be 1.
```

In case if you want to display ascii values of complete String, you need to do this.

```
String name = "admin";
char[] val = name.toCharArray();
for(char b: val) {
 int c = b;
 System.out.println("Ascii value of " + b + " is: " + c);
}
```

Your output, in this case, will be: 
Ascii value of a is: 97
Ascii value of d is: 100
Ascii value of m is: 109
Ascii value of i is: 105
Ascii value of n is: 110

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is:

**For whole String into ASCII :**

---

```
public class ConvertToAscii{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      String abc = "admin";
      int []arr = new int[abc.length()];
      System.out.println("THe asscii value of each character is: ");
      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          arr[i] = abc.charAt(i); // assign the integer value of character i.e ascii
          System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
      }
    }
}
```

---

**The output is:**

`THe asscii value of each character is: 
 97 100 109 105 110`

---

Here, `abc.charAt(i)` gives the single character of String array:
When we assign each character to integer type then, the compiler do type conversion as,

`arr[i] = (int) character // Here, every individual character is coverted in ascii value`

**But, for single character:**

`String name = admin;
asciiValue = (int) name.charAt(0);// for character 'a'
System.out.println(asciiValue);`