# How do I convert a number to a certain letter?

Tags: java

I want to convert 1 to 'A' and 2 to 'B' and so on. Is there a specific formula in java for capital letters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to ASCII value in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-string-to-ascii-value-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

Sure, `(char) ('A' + n - 1)` will map the integers from 1 to 26 to the characters `'A'` to `'Z'`.