# Using Ascii Characters instead of Char

Tags: java, char, ascii

So I have a piece of code below that loads in a text file and analyzes it to show the percentages of each letter from a word or sentence that's stored within a text file.

Instead of using `char []` letters, I want to be able to use `ASCII` code instead.

I am unsure how to go about doing this so any help would be appreciated!

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class testing {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void main(String[] args){ 
            Scanner scan;
                    try {
                        scan = new Scanner(new File("G:/test.txt")); //change directory to load in text file
                            } 
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("File was not found ");
                                return;
                  }
                  int[] count = new int[26];
                    int total = 0;
                        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                            String text2 = scan.nextLine();
                                System.out.println ("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println ("                            Words loaded in from the file: " + text2);
                                System.out.println ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.print("\n");
                                System.out.print("");
                    char[] letters = text2.toCharArray();
                            char[] letters1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n','o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
                                for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                                    for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
                                if(letters[i] == letters1[j]) {
                          count[j]++;
                          total = total + 1;
                          break;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                                for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
                      System.out.format("|    "+ letters1[i]+"    ");
                  }
                    System.out.println ("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
                    float percentage = 0; 
                    if (count[i] > 0)
                        percentage = ((float) count[i]/total)*100;
                      System.out.format("|  "+percentage+ "%%   ");
                      }
                        }
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-string-to-ascii-value-in-java

Answer (score 2):

A `char` in Java is just an unsigned 16 bits integer containing the Unicode codepoint associated with that character (at least if it is in the BMP). And Unicode is a superset of ASCII, so your `char[]` already contain the ASCII values of the characters you're processing.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` can be converted to `int` (0-127) ([see here](http://www.asciitable.com/)), so its really easy to save it in an array. You just have to edit the parts of your code where you work with the latin alphabet and substitute it with a bigger array.

This should work:

```
int[] count = new int[128];
int total = 0;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String text2 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("                            Words loaded in from the file: " + text2);
    System.out.println ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("");
    char[] letters = text2.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            count[letters[i]]++;
            total++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        float percentage = 0;
        if (count[1] > 0)
            percentage = ((float) count[i] / total) * 100;
        System.out.format("|  " + percentage + "%%   ");
    }
}
```

I dont know what the following part should do, so I skipped it:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
                      System.out.format("|    "+ letters1[i]+"    ");
}
```