# Integer.parseInt not parsing a string into integer

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
length = sc.nextLine();
length_to_play = Integer.parseInt(length);
```

I have tried using length.trim() and length.replaceAll() to discard the whitespaces, but didn't work.
I'm having Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "y"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at speedwords.first_activity(speedwords.java:27)
    at speedwords.main(speedwords.java:338)
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: @ArhatBaid post complete stacktrace, it will show you the string also.

Comment: yes.. whenever i input a character i'm getting a "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException.

Comment: @ArhatBaid character or number you are inputting

Comment: i'm trying to input an integer, but whenever a character is input a print message should be shown to the user( I'm using if-else). But on inputting a character this error is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user is inputting numbers, you should use [`sc.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()). This way you don't need to write the parsing yourself.

If you're expecting strings of characters and want to convert them into `int`s, you can use [`Character.getNumericValue(myChar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(int)) on each character of the input string individually.

Comment: if i use sc.nextInt () , then how can i print a message to the user using a IF-ELSE block? I was hoping that on inputting a character i can convert it to it's ASCII integer value and check in the IF block

Comment: Okay, you might want to edit the question to mention that you want to convert characters specifically.

Comment: but isn't a character also a possible string? even if i input, a string for eg "tyf" the parseInt() doesn't return the ASCII integer values.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. What would you expect as an int result for "tyf"? The sum of its characters' ASCII values or a concatenation of the values as a string? I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood thefunctionality of

```
Integer.parseInt();
```

**From the Java Docs**

> ```
>   Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The 
>   characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that 
>   the first character may be an ASCII minus sign <code>'-'</code> 
>   (<code>'&#92;u002D'</code>) to indicate a negative value. The resulting 
>   integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 
>   10 were given as arguments to the 
>   {@link #parseInt(java.lang.String, int)} method.
>
>   @param s       a <code>String</code> containing the <code>int</code>
>               representation to be parsed
>   @return     the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
>   @exception  NumberFormatException  if the string does not contain a
>                 parsable integer.
> ```

```
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return parseInt(s,10);
    }
```

Comment: But shouldn't parseInt() return the ASCII integer value of the string?

Comment: @ArhatBaid look for the inner implementation , you will get all your answers

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the documentation on [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

As you can see the parsed String is converted into integer value and if the value is not an integer it throws [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).

> Why are you expecting it should return ASCII integer value?
>
> **Answer:** For your kind information we are passing String, not a `char` which has independent ASCII value. If you want the ASCII of each character in your String then you can have a look at this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16458564/3898076).

Comment: yes that is what I did at last in a little different way.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I'm posting the answer that I found worked best for the case i want. But thank you all for your help.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
length = sc.nextLine();
//length_to_play = Integer.valueOf(length); didn't work
char ch = length.charAt(0);
length_to_play=Character.getNumericValue(ch); //worked
```