# convert each item of a char[] to its ASCII code

Tags: java, string, char, ascii

How can I convert each item of a char[] (char array) to its ascii code? `char_arr[i].charAt(0)` doesn't work as the method doesn't exist. I can't use the `toString` method for `char_arr[i]`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by mona on 2/25/16.
 */
public class FunnyString {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        int num_str;
        num_str=sc.nextInt();
        Boolean flag=true;

        for (int i=0;i<num_str;i++){
            StringBuilder strb  = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());
            StringBuilder str_reverse=strb.reverse();
            Char[] strb_arr=strb.toString().toCharArray();
            Char[] strb_rev_arr=str_reverse.toString().toCharArray();
            for (int i=1; i<strb_arr.length;i++){
                if (Math.abs(strb_arr[i]-strb_arr[i-1])!=Math.abs(strb_rev_arr[i]-strb_rev_arr[i-1])){
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag==false){
            System.out.println("Not funny");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Funny");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can just cast 'int'

Comment: "ASCII" is the wrong term. Java strings are counted sequences of Unicode/UTF-16 code units (`Char`).  Just keep in mind that real-world strings (containing [emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)) for example) are more complicated than your algorithm can handle. See the caveat for [StringBuilder.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to ASCII value in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-string-to-ascii-value-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: cast it to `int`

```
char[] chars;
for (char aChar : chars) {
    System.out.println("chars = " + (int) aChar);
}
```

Comment: That will work for all ASCII characters. It will return numbers > 127 for non-ASCII characters (but those aren't in ASCII anyway, so that's probably fine).

Answer (score 0):

Traverse through the array, assigning each char value to an int by casting, i.e.,

```
char_to_ascii[i] = (int) char_arr[i] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use casting to integer (int) , or just add 0 to your char.

See this

```
char[] cs = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
for (Character c : cs)
{
    System.out.println(c + 0);
}
```

Output

```
97
98
99
```

See it's ascii codes of given chars http://www.asciitable.com/ .

Additionally you could get a char from a numeric value.

```
char[] cs = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
for (Character c : cs)
{
    System.out.println(c + 0);
    System.out.println( (char)(c + 0) );
}
```

Output

```
97
a
98
b
99
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Because elements of `char[]` are UTF-16 code units, the standard numerical representation is in the form of backslash, "u", four hexadecimal digits. For example, 'a' is represented as '\u0061'.

Also, note that some Unicode codepoints are encoded in two UTF-16 code units. For example, the musical quarter note "" (might not display with the font your browser is using with this web page).

```
for (char c : "abc123".toCharArray())
{
    System.out.println(String.format("\\u%04X", (int)c));
}
```