# How to take an array of strings and get the ASCII value of each character in EACH string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, ascii

So i have an array of strings. Each index contains a string like "abc" "fnsb" "feros". I want to pass in this array of strings through a for loop that can get each character's ASCII value of ALL the strings listed above and possibly store each string's character's ASCII value in another array. For example, if my array of strings has

```
mystrings[0] = hi
mystrings[1] = hello
mystrings[2] = farewell
```

I want it to take the ASCII values of "h" and "i" and store it in an `newarray[0]`, then take the ASCII values of "h","e","l","l","o" and store it into `newarray[1]`, and ETC.

Note: Above is a bunch of pseudocode. Here is what I actually have:

```
String[] mystrings= new String[100];
double [] newarray = new double[100];
        for (int x=0; x<100; x++){
            char character = mystrings[x].charAt(x);
            int ascii = (int) character;
            newarray[x] = ascii;
            System.out.println(newarray[x]);
        }
```

Another note: There are indeed multiple strings stored in each index of the mystrings array. It's just in another part of my code that I don't want to share. So please assume that the "mystrings" array is properly filled with various strings. Thank you!

Comment: You want to store multiple ASCII values in a single variable of type `double`?  How do you imagine that working?

Comment: How can you store multiple ASCII values in a single double? Just adding them all up? Some sort of encoding? As it stands it looks like you have the wrong data struct for `newarray`

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  Unless all the Strings in mystrings are 100 characters long it will quickly error out.  And until that happens you will be storing the ASCII codes for "h", "e", and "r" into the first three elements of newarray.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert character to ASCII numeric value in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-character-to-ascii-numeric-value-in-java)

Comment: this looks more like an assignment given in school which you couldn't answer.

Comment: @HotLicks i know it doesn't make any sense, that's how i know it's wrong. why else would i post it here?

Comment: @MohammedAtif thanks, but it's a smaller part of a huge program. but really thanks so much for your well needed contribution to my problem. useless. go troll somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is that you demonstrate a general lack of comprehension of what you're doing.  We're not going to write your program for you, so you need to work on one misunderstanding at a time, rather than attempting something that is so far beyond your abilities.

Comment: @user7428413, `but it's a smaller part of a huge program`, then you must explain the problem rather the approach. http://xyproblem.info/ . Go through this link, it will hardly take 10 minutes to read it. Based on that, ask your question again. And yea, unless you get trolled for your code, you cant improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue in your pseudocode is that the result must be not simply an array, but an array of arrays:

```
int[][] newarray = new int[mystrings.length][];
```

The second issue is that getting character codes must be done in a separate loop, nested inside the first one. The loop must go from zero to `mystring[i].length()`:

```
char character = mystrings[x].charAt(y);
//                                   ^
```

Note that `charAt` parameter is *not* the same as `x` in `mystrings[x]`, because it needs to be a separate loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "hello";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Java 8 solution:

```
String[] mystrings = {"hi", "bye"};

List<List<Integer>> result;

result = Arrays.stream(mystrings)
                 .map(s -> s.chars()
                                   .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                 .map(chars -> chars.stream()
                                       .map(Integer::new)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
                 )
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

... and the output would be:

```
[[104, 105], [98, 121, 101]]
```