# Replace all characters in string beside a-z 0-9 and ,

Tags: java, android, regex, string

Hey I want to sanitize a string and only allow it to have a-z A-Z (also other languates, not only english) and , I tried doing the `ReplaceAll([^a-z 0-9,])` but it is deleting other languates.. can someone show me how can I manage to only sanitize special characters and also won't delete emojis from it?

Comment: `ReplaceAll()` isn't even a PHP function...

Comment: Use: `str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]+", "");`

Comment: Can you clarify what `but it is deleting other languages` means?

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the a-z and 0-9 characters' ASCII code, and if the current character is *not* one of them, do what you wish. 
On how to get the ascii value of a character, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-character-to-ascii-numeric-value-in-java).

EDIT: the idea is that a-z and 0-9 the characters are next to each other. So just write a simple function that returns a `boolean` whether your current character is one of these, and if not, replace. 
For this though, you will have to replace one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this regular expression and AFAIK it works...

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

It replaces any character that isn't in the set a-z, A-Z, or 0-9 with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can do

```
yourString.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", "");
```

The regular expression `[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+` match all characters that are no a unicode letter or a decimal number.

If you need only characters (not numbers) you can use the regular expression `[^\\p{L}]+` as follow:

```
yourString.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]+", "");
```