# Character to ascii conversion

Tags: java

I've been trying to convert a character to ASCII. Please help out, here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CharToAscii {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENter the character you want to convert");
        char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(int(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `System.out.println((int)c);` .

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-character-to-ascii-numeric-value-in-java

Comment: @Aominè got the answer. You seem to be using `int(c)` as if it is a function, which it isn't. You're trying to cast between data types, and to do this you put the parenthesis around the data type you're casting the data to.

Comment: 1) I should point out that this question's title and description is ambiguous.  Based on the code, you are **actually** trying to convert the character to the *decimal representation* of an ASCII character code.  2) For characters in the ASCII range (0x00 to 0x127) the number will be what you expect.  For others ... well ... the character is strictly not-convertable ... and what you will see is a UTF-16 code-unit, representing the character, or part of it.

Comment: To @StephenC's point. there is a problem with expecting ASCII at all. Most people responding to the prompt "Enter the character you want to convert" would not expect a limitation of [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) characters. Some might type letters from their name, say "é" or "శ్రీ" (["\u0c36\u0c4d\u0c30\u0c40"](http://javajee.com/unicode-escapes-in-java)). I might type the character "…" or my favorite punctuation mark "—" or favorite symbol "". Java supports them all, as do most web pages—including this one. _Unicode…since 1991™._

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(int(c));
```

Line gives the ERROR

[TypeCasting](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html) should be done by placing the type in round braces.

```
System.out.println((int)(c));
```

Is the CORRECT implementation.

Comment: Ermm .... this ignores the fact that not all `char` values map to an ASCII character.  Hence "CORRECT" is an overstatement.