# How to split string by ± in java

Tags: java, string, split

I was trying to split my string using ± (alt + 0177) sign, but it dos't detect it.
I also tried indexOf() but its not work

```
    String myString = "20±1";
    if(myString.indexOf('±')>-1){
         System.out.println("We are in here.........");
    }
```

Comment: `.indexOf` takes a `char` as parameter, not a string! Moreover, finding the index of a char won't split the string on its own.

Comment: You wrote `String` wrong and `indexOf` takes a char as param. Fixed those errors it works

Comment: `myString.split("±")` should split your string

Comment: System.out.println(a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("±", a.length())));

Comment: Sorry its typing mistake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ascii value for the '±' sign.

An easy way get the ascii value as shown in this reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-character-to-ascii-numeric-value-in-java)

In your case:

```
final int ascii = (int) '±';
final String myString = "20±1";

if(myString.indexOf(ascii)>-1){
     System.out.println("We are in here.........");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use function split()

```
String myString = "20±1";
String result[] = myString.split("±");
//result[0] = 20
//result[1] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*Your String*/
    String myString = "20±1";


    /*If you want to split String you can use String.split("your string regex here")
     * and it will create String array without specified string regex with left, right 
     * side of string or multiple strings depending on occurrence of specified string regex*/

    String[] splitted = myString.split("±");


    /*Just to validate output*/
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use also `StringTokenizer` for this problem:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class happy {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String myString = "20±1";
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(myString,"±");
        String a="";
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            a=st.nextToken();
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```