# convert string to list of int in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

I have a string = "1337" and I want to convert it to a list of Int, I tried to get every element in the string and convert it to Int like this string[0].toInt but I didn't get the number I get the Ascii value, I can do it with this Character.getNumericValue(number), How I do it without using a built it function? with good complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "without using a built in function"?

`string[0].toInt` gives you the ASCII value of the character because the `fun get(index: Int)` on String has a return type of `Char`, and a `Char` behaves closer to a `Number` than a `String`. `"0".toInt() == 0` will yield true, but `'0'.toInt() == 0` will yield false. The difference being the first one is a string and the second is a character.

A oneliner

```kotlin
string.split("").filterNot { it.isBlank() }.map { it.toInt() }
```

Explanation: `split("")` will take the string and give you a list of every character as a string, however, it will give you an empty string at the beginning, which is why we have `filterNot { it.isBlank() }`, we then can use `map` to transform every string in our list to `Int`

If you want something less functional and more imperative that doesn't make use of functions to convert  there is this

```kotlin
val ints = mutableListOf<Int>()       //make a list to store the values in
for (c: Char in "1234") {             //go through all of the characters in the string
    val numericValue = c - '0'        //subtract the character '0' from the character we are looking at
    ints.add(numericValue)            //add the Int to the list
}
```

The reason why `c - '0'` works is because the ASCII values for the digits are all in numerical order starting with 0, and when we subtract one character from another, we get the difference between their ASCII values.

This will give you some funky results if you give it a string that doesn't have only digits in it, but it will not throw any exceptions.

Comment: I guess `.split("")` is redundant, as String already implements `CharSequence`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu yes, because String implements CharSequence the split is strictly not necessary, however, it will give a list strings, but using CharSequence methods will give a list of characters, and considering digitToInt is still experimental (though I'm sure stable, it is just not guaranteed to stick around) I'd rather stick in string land. As you can see from the various answers, there are a lot of ways of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As in Java and by converting `Char` to `Int` [you get the ascii equivalence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-character-to-ascii-numeric-value-in-java).

You can instead:

```
val values = "1337".map { it.toString().toInt() }

println(values[0]) // 1 
println(values[1]) // 3
// ...
```

Comment: Starting with Kotlin 1.5 `Char.digitToInt()` has been introduced.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu thanks for pointing out, just to mention that `Char.digitToInt()` is still experimental.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this? No-digits are filtered out. The digits are then converted into integers:

```
val string = "1337"
  
val xs = string.filter{ it.isDigit() }.map{ it.digitToInt() }
```

Requires Kotlin 1.4.30 or higher and this option:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
```